# React App blank page when deploying production build

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react, so apologies if this is basic - but following a promising learning curve building the site, I've spent c9hrs trying to get it deployed :(

The info is as follows...

1.Runs fine as a development build on my machine.

2.Creating a production build through 'npm run build' results in it being built with the assumption its hosted at the server root - see below;

```
file sizes after gzip:

  278.93 KB  build/static/js/2.a3ca1e82.chunk.js
  42.16 KB   build/static/js/main.1a0b5ce7.chunk.js
  33.88 KB   build/static/css/main.75362cf6.chunk.css
  24.72 KB   build/static/css/2.3cd6815b.chunk.css
  762 B      build/static/js/runtime~main.a8a9905a.js

The project was built assuming it is hosted at the server root.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.
For example, add this to build it for GitHub Pages:

  "homepage" : "http://myname.github.io/myapp",

The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:

  serve -s build
```

Running 'serve -s build' results in a local deployment of the production build on localhost:5000 - but with the blank screen problem present

...and the issue is consistent on the production deployment on Amazon S3. This can be seen live on  [www.cotswoldcohost.co.uk](http://www.cotswoldcohost.co.uk) right now.

Looking a the source it appears to be finding index.html, and the console highlights a type error with particles.js - which maybe a separate issue from the rendering problem.

Any advice really appreciated - happy to provide any more info that you may require!

Comment: Your site is being served up. It's erroring very early. In particular at ` particles.js:668` Is this something you wrote? Or are importing?

Comment: Reload the page with the network tab in the devs tools open, do all the files load properly, or are you getting 404s on anything?

Comment: It all loads fine, particle.js is throwing an error due to a value being passed to a function that is not type checking as a function or null.

Comment: Thanks both - particles.js is imported, and I've checked all the files load properly - there are no 404's

Answer (score 1):

I went through the same issue recently whilst using `react-particles-js` in a React app, getting

```
TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not object
```

on console.

It happens I was working on a old project with outdated package versions and therefore there was an incompatibility between `react`, `react-scripts` and `react-particles-js`. Updating packages to the following versions fixed my problem:

> ```
> react: ^17.0.2,
> react-dom: ^17.0.2,
> react-particles-js: ^2.7.1,
> react-scripts: 3.4.4,
> eslint: ^6.6.0
> ```

Comment: I’d recommend `react-tsparticles` for particles animations, it supports React 16 and 17

Answer (score 0):

When I go to [www.cotswoldcohost.co.uk](http://www.cotswoldcohost.co.uk) on Chrome, my console gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function`.

If this is the true underlying issue and not the Particle.js issue, then it's possibly an export issue in your app. I would check for these things:

1. Circular dependencies / imports
2. Importing a default export incorrectly (usually an import with curly braces that shouldn't be using braces)
3. A missing `import` statement

Answer (score 0):

Just been through the entire project and removed all references to particles.js as its not critical...and its working. That was a long day, but I learnt a lot. Thanks for everyones input.

Comment: I suggest you a React component for particles: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tsparticles